# How to Integrate Angular Apps in different repositories on a local workspace

Tags: angular, git

I am currently having issues with integrating multiple Angular 17 apps in different git submodules with one another.

When compiling any angular app in the workspace root, everything is fine, `ng build [PROJECT NAME]` works as expected.

However, when cloning the git submodule repository, executing said command produces

`Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.`

My question is, is there a way to be able to execute said command on the submodule?

I need this because of CI/CD and git branches simple do not work on my context.